# Why is "Build Active Architecture Only" even an option for release builds?

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

Why would anyone ever set this option to YES for a release build in practice? So you gain a little build time, but how often do you make release builds? And why would you ever want only the architecture for a release build to be only that of the connected device (even if your connected device has the lowest common denominator of backwards compatible architectures you are supporting)?

Comment: The Debug and Release options you see there are just the auto-created build configurations. You can add more, and name them whatever you want. The option is there for each individual build configuration in your project for flexibility. The Release configuration is not special from Xcode's perspective.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite ah I see. Feel free to answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I guess the question was whether he should use the 'Build Active Architerture only' for whatever scheme he decides to use for 'App store' builds

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Release is not just for submitting to the app store. Selecting a release build turns on lots of compiler optimizations that generate fast code, and the memory footprint is different. It can be useful to test release builds for various reasons.

Swift code in particular is really slow in debug builds if it deals with lots of arrays. It's better with Swift 1.2, but still quite slow.

If you're testing on your development device it doesn't really make sense to compile for all the different supported architectures. Building is much faster for just your active architecture.

Comment: Do any changes to this setting in production build target will affect the app submitting to the app store or will it affect only while debugging.

Comment: @Sujananth is missing the question-mark, but I guess that option is completely ignored for App-store builds ???

Comment: If (like mine) your `Xcode` for some reason does not show that setting, simply add User-Defined with **`ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH`** as key and `NO` as value.

Answer (score 8):

The Debug and Release options you see there are just the auto-created build configurations. You can add more, and name them whatever you want.

The option is there for each individual build configuration in your project for flexibility. The Release configuration is not special from Xcode's perspective.

As an example, here's the list of configurations in one of my projects:

[image]

You can add more configurations in the info tab of the project info, then they will be displayed separately under each build setting that you expand, so you can configure them separately.

Comment: Added "Release App Store" & "Release Beta" configuration by duplicating Release(Default created by xcode). Command line build is working for "Release" but not working for "Release App Store" & "Release Beta". Errors saying few header files not found. Anything missing?

error: ‘Cordova/CDVViewController.h’ file not found
error: ‘Cordova/CDV.h’ file not found

Comment: Probably, the `$(CONFIGURATION)` variable is used somewhere, and like my build-script, only `Debug` and `Release` are supported!!